# during high load on yarn cluster, spark session take more time to initialize

Tags: apache-spark, livy

I observed that spark session take time to initialize when there is high load on cluster , can someone help me to understand why this happen, is spark maintain session pool somewhere and during high load it is not able to get the session from pool as pool get exhausted? or is it because of resource crunch , I observed that job started running but take time to create session
Note: I am using Apache livy to submit spark job